# I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong

Tags: javascript

> I keep getting this error and I'm not sure what to do? I'm trying to
>       make a flip card game.
>       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
>       at flipCard (main.js:42)
>       at createBoard (main.js:53)
>       at main.js:59

```
var cards = [
    {
    rank: 'queen',
    suit: 'diamonds',
    cardImage: 'images/queen-of-diamonds.png'
    },
    {
    rank: 'queen',
    suit: 'hearts',
    cardImage: 'images/queen-of-hearts.png'
    },
    {
    rank: 'king',
    suit: 'diamonds',
    cardImage: 'images/king-of-diamonds.png'
    },
    {
    rank: 'king',
    suit: 'hearts',
    cardImage: 'images/king-of-hearts.png'
    }
    ]
    var cardsInPlay = [cards]
    var checkForMatch = function () {
    this.cardImage.setAttribute(src)
    if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
    window.alert('You found a match!')
    } else {
    window.alert('Sorry, try again')
    }
    }

var flipCard = function (cardId) {
this.cardId.getAttribute('data-id')
checkForMatch()
console.log('User flipped ' + cards[cardId].rank)
console.log('User flipped ' + cards[cardId].cardImage)
console.log('User flipped ' + cards[cardId].suit)
}
function createBoard () {
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
var cardElement = document.createElement('img')
cardElement.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png')
cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i)
cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCard())
cardElement.appendChild(game-board)
}
}
createBoard()
cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId])`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here:

```
cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCard())
```

you're invoking flipCard rather then pass a function reference.
try to change the code accordingly

```
var flipCard = function(cardId) {
  //no need of 'this' here
  cardId.getAttribute('data-id')
  checkForMatch()
  console.log('User flipped ' + cards[cardId].rank)
  console.log('User flipped ' + cards[cardId].cardImage)
  console.log('User flipped ' + cards[cardId].suit)
}

function createBoard () {
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    var cardElement = document.createElement('img')
    cardElement.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png')
    cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i)
    cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCard.bind(null, cardElement))
    cardElement.appendChild(game-board)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't going to be a `this` value in checkForMatch, as it is defined in the global space and you are calling it directly. You probably want to call it using `call`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

```
checkForMatch.call(this);
```